# Unable to load Android APK in ARC Welder

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I would like to ask for your assistance in loading my APK on ARCWelder on my Chromebook.
I have successfully installed ARC Welder from this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) but when I tried to load my APK, it just keeps on loading like the image below.

[image]

I tried reinstalling ARC Welder multiple times and encountered the same thing.
I tried different APKs and no luck as well.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please file a bug against ARC Welder: [goo.gl/megdlG](http://goo.gl/megdlG). Also, please collect Javascript logs and include those in your report. You can get the logs by typing "chrome://inspect/#apps" into your browser URL bar, clicking "inspect" next to the ARC welder link, and copying them from the "Console" view.

Comment: Have you tried loading an "Hello World" Android app? Does that work at the very least? If it does work for "Hello World", I would try loading progressively more complex applications. http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508795) for this and found out that it is a bug on **Chrome OS 43's** time zone. They fixed it on **Chrome OS 44**. So simply update your OS to 44.

In case **Chrome OS 43** is the most updated version, try to change your download channel from **stable** to **beta** under **Settings**.

Hope this may help somebody in the future. Thanks!

Comment: What if we trying to run apk on chrome browser in window's pc?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I found that using *Chrome* rather than *Chromium* overcomes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. The reason is the data saved location you choose in Chrome App Launcher settings. And ARC Welder can only read or write the data of the location we choose.
Hence, you can push you apk files into the path you choose or choose the ARC welder, right click -> app information , click the icon to remove the read and write limits.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Lloyd Pique, you can get the logs by typing "chrome://inspect/#apps" into your browser URL bar, clicking "inspect" next to the ARC welder link. If you find the following in the log:

NativeClient: NaCl's GDB debug stub requires --no-sandbox flag on Windows.

Turn NaCl debugging off under chrome://flags/

Comment: On my linux machine I get a js error: unable to create 'innerHTML'

Answer (score -3):

what you need to do:

- Install ARC Welder and download your APK files, as per our previous tutorial.
- Launch ARC Welder and choose the “Add your APK” option and select your APK.
  -It’s a good idea to click “Launch App at this point to test the app and see if it works properly (many apps such as YouTube, Gmail, Google Maps, or Netflix may not).
  -Next, choose the Download ZIP option.
- Navigate to the folder where you downloaded that ZIP file.
  -Unzip the file you just created to a new folder (or the same one).
- Open the Chrome web browser, choose “More tools” from the settings menu, and then click on “Extensions.”

  - At the top of the page, check the box that says Developer mode.
- Click the button that says “Load unpacked extension” and select the folder where you just unzipped your file.

That’s it! If everything properly, you should see a new entry in your Extensions list for the app you just installed. It will also show up in your Chrome app launcher.**strong text**

for more reference you can see the below links

http://liliputing.com/2015/04/how-to-run-multiple-android-apps-through-chrome-with-arc-welder.html

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering but as you can see on the image on my question, no "Launch App" or "Download Zip" to click.